# notifyDataSetChanged() not working for me

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview which display multiple data from my database using base adapter  in different class. I want to refresh my listview everytime I delete or add an item to my database.

Here is my code but its not refreshing my listview. Please help me where should I put the `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
BaseAdapter ad = ((orderadapter)list.getAdapter());
ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First I decalre adapter as a global variable:

```
       public ListAdapter adapter = null;
```

Now I initialize my listview(in which I have to put the items) in onCreate() method. The layout for this listview is defined in the xml file:

```
       listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myList);
```

Now I get all the values to be shown in an arraylist and then initialize the adapter with this arraylist(you can use any other data storage technique as well):

```
       adapter = new ListAdapter(availableMessageNotifications,MessageNotificationActivity.this);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

And then I set onItemClickListener on every item of the list:

```
      OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener (){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,long id) {
      //your code for an item clicked.
     }
     listView.setOnItemClickListener (listener);
```

I hope this will help you.

You should call notifyDataSetChanged() from UI thread :

```
       yourList.remove(position);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm using a BaseAdapter class and how to I create a new adapter to call notifyDataSetChanged()? This is my code                                            BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter)list.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

I have face same problem but now solved using below code.

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```